# Sliding Bar Under Navigation jQuery CSS

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, slide

```
$(".myNav").hover (
    function () {
          $('.bar').animate({width: "102px"}, 500)
          $(".myNav").animate ({backgroundColor: "#FF9900"}, 500)
  }, 
    function(){
      $('.bar').animate({width: "-0"}, 500)
          $(".myNav").animate ({backgroundColor: "#ffb84d"}, 500)
    }
);
```

I'm using this code to add a sliding bar under a nav button but it affects every button with the same class when hovered over.

I was also wondering if there was a way to do this purely with CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/cgcLe1hs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS you can use `transition` to make the animations and `:pseudo-elements` to recreate the bar; try this:

```css
.myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0px;
}
.myNav {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffb84d;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .5s linear;
}
.myNav:hover {
  background: #FF9900;
}
.myNav:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}
.myNav:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="myNav">
      Home
    </td>
    <td class="myNav">
      About
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

<sub>Aside I suggest to avoid the use of tables to create a menu instrad use list with a elements and style it to be side by side</sub>

Comment: That works brilliant thank you :) aye I normally use divs and lists cheers

Comment: I don't have enough reputation but when I do i'll mark it up :)

Comment: Np mate i'm here to help and learn the rep it's a plus .... glad to ehlp U @DannyPearson